# How to pass literal text to a function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R (and programming in general), and having some trouble wrapping my head around functions.  I am trying to write a function for plotting a histogram of a given variable with a normal curve overlaid.  Here, I have code that does this given a specific `variable` in `data`:

```
    dev.new()
    ggplot(data,aes(x = variable)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),binwidth=.2)+
    geom_density(na.rm=TRUE)+
    stat_function(fun=dnorm, args=list(mean=mean(data$variable,na.rm=TRUE), 
    sd=sd(data$variable, na.rm=TRUE)), linetype=4, colour="red")
```

This code works just fine if I put in the specific `data` and `variable`, but if I try to pass the same things through a function, it no longer does.  For instance:

```
   plotnormal<-function(data,variable){
    dev.new()
    ggplot(data,aes(x = variable)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),binwidth=.2)+
    geom_density(na.rm=TRUE)+
    stat_function(fun=dnorm, args=list(mean=mean(data$variable,na.rm=TRUE), 
    sd=sd(data$variable, na.rm=TRUE)), linetype=4, colour="red")}

   plotnormal(data, variable)
```

What gives?  Is there any way to just pass the exact text that I enter into the function?

Comment: Use `data[[variable]]` instead of `data$variable` when passing string column names into a function to be subsetted

Comment: @RichardScriven You should put that as an answer, as it solves the problem ;)

Comment: Likely a duplicate, but I went ahead and posted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing a string variable name into a function where you plan on using that name in a subset of a data frame or other structure, use

```
data[[variable]]
```

instead of

```
data$variable
```

For more, read `help(Extract)`  Also, you'll want to use `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`.  Then your updated function should be

```
plotnormal <- function(data, variable) {
    dev.new()
    ggplot(data, aes_string(x = variable)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = .2) +
    geom_density(na.rm = TRUE) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean  = mean(data[[variable]], na.rm = TRUE), 
    sd = sd(data[[variable]], na.rm = TRUE)), linetype = 4, colour = "red")
}
```

Hitting the space bar every once in a while helps too.